# Making a text disappears when another text appears with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box').on('click', function() {
        var elmDay = $(this).data('day');
        $('.' + elmDay).toggleClass('display');
    });
});
```

Please, visit this site to understand -> http://jsfiddle.net/g42d8pjp/

When you click in the first box, one text with background red will show, right?, them if you click in the other box, other text with a red background will show too.

Can i make the first text with the red background disappear if the second box is clicked??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change the css via javascript/jquery? Here is a quickly done updated jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ykoo873e/

You can just set all the other styles for those divs to 'display: none' and only set the one:

```
$('.display').css('display', 'none');
$('.display.' + elmDay).css('display', 'block');
```

Though you could also just dynamically change the html inside the div like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/m5hL220d/

Answer (score 0):

Add a common class for the boxes like 'day'

```
<div class="row">
   <div data-day="thursday" class="box thursday-box col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://pubcrawlnovo-black.site44.com/assets/images/box.png">
   </div>
   <div data-day="friday" class="box friday-box col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://pubcrawlnovo-black.site44.com/assets/images/box.png">
   </div>
   <div class="col-9">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="thursday display day">
   <h1 class="title">SOMETHING1 </h1>
   <p>SOMETHING1</p>
</div>
<div class="friday display day">
   <h1 class="title">SOMETHING2</h1>
   <p>SOMETHING2</p>
</div>
```

Hide elements with this class attached on click.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var days = $('.day');
    $('.box').on('click', function() {
        var elmDay = $(this).data('day');
        days.addClass('display');
        $('.' + elmDay).toggleClass('display');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/g42d8pjp/1/

```
 <div id="thursday" class="thursday display">
            <h1 class="title">SOMETHING1 </h1>
            <p>SOMETHING1</p>
        </div>




        <div id="friday" class="friday display">
            <h1 class="title">SOMETHING2</h1>
            <p>SOMETHING2</p>
        </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
$('.box').on('click', function() {
    var elmDay = $(this).data('day');
    if (elmDay == 'thursday')
    {
        $('#thursday').show();
        $('#friday').hide();

    }else
    {
        $('#friday').show();
        $('#thursday').hide();
    }

    //$('.' + elmDay).toggleClass('display');
});
```

});